# Source code for Kie-Execution Server

Tags: java, drools, kie-server

From where I can find the Kie-Execution Server source code for the latest stable version (6.3.0.Final)?

I found the following website where source code for 6.2.0.Final is located, but I didn't find any place where I can download the 6.3.0.Final version.

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.kie/kie-server-client/6.2.0.Final/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is on github, hope it helps: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/tree/master/kie-server-parent.